# What is the silencing mechanism of AGO1,AGO3 and AGO4?

Tags: rna, microrna

I read that this proteins lack of slicer activity, so what mechanism do they use to perform gene regulation?

Comment: Just the presence of a large protein complex in the 5'-UTR of an mRNA can prevent ribosome binding and therefore translation. I'm not saying that that is the actual mechanism, but it's plausible.

Comment: Ago(s) of what organism? I presume you are talking about mammalian Ago. I am asking this because Ago proteins with same name may not be orthologs; for e.g. Drosophila Ago3 (along with Piwi and Aub) belongs to the Piwi family which in vertebrates includes Piwi, Piwi-like and Piwi-2. Also, there are differences between Ago1&2 of Drosophila and mammals. Plants have many Ago proteins (even *C.elegans*)

Answer (score -2):

Paper by Zinovyev and colleagues in the paper "Mathematical modeling of microRNA‐mediated mechanisms of translation repression" find that there are reports to 9 different mechanisms of miRNA-regulation.

> Here we are reviewing available experimental data on all reported mechanisms of microRNA action, grouping them in a way which elucidates the main details supporting each of these proposed mechanisms.

Here is a list of the mentioned mechanisms:

> M1: Cap-40S Initiation Inhibition
>
> M2: 60S Ribosomal Unit Joining Inhibition
>
> M3: Elongation Inhibition
>
> M4: Ribosome Drop-Off
>
> M5: Co-translational Nascent Protein Degradation
>
> M6: Sequestration in P-Bodies
>
> M7: mRNA Decay
>
> M8:  mRNA Cleavage
>
> M9: Transcriptional Inhibition Through microRNA-Mediated Chromatin Reorganization Following by Gene Silencing

Also here is a link to the [Pubmed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/23377975) entry of the article:

Comment: Perhaps you could briefly summarize the mechanisms.

Comment: And could you add a proper citation with a web link? -1